# Como funciona o método .removeAttr() do jquery quando o mesmo possui dois parâmetros?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou analisando um código que em certo ponto tem a seguinte linha:

*o seletor #select é apenas um exemplo.*

```
$("#select option:selected"). 
  removeAttr('disabled').
  siblings().
  removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

o que este segundo `.removeAttr()` faz já que recebi 2 parâmetros? o certo n seria um método `.attr()` para definir o atributo disabled como 'disabled'?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

O método removeAttr() apenas recebe um parâmetro string. O segundo parâmetro é ignorado por isso esse código deve estar errado.

Para remover múltiplos atributos ao mesmo tempo podemos separá-los com um espaço.

```
$("#element").removeAttr("disabled readonly");
```